# run xterm as subprocess not take startup script/environment

Tags: boot, process, xterm

I am using Debian/Jessie linux, 
When I launch `xterm` from my project to run external project, `xterm` here not takes my environments variables, in other way it is not takes the startup scripts `.bashrc` or `.profile`, while it works fine as normal terminal on my desktop.

to reproduce it I will use lua, just run this script to see the "export" of sub `xterm` values.

```
os.execute('xterm -e "export ; read -rsp $\'Press any key to continue\' -n1 key"')
```

How can I tell/force `xterm` to take this profiles startup?

Comment: My real project is a simple programming editor that run programs/script by call xterm as wrapper of running the program.

https://github.com/parmaja/miniedit/blob/master/source/editor/EditorRun.pas#L432